# Solve $x^7=e$ in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a group having the property that $\exists a \in G$ such that $\forall x \in G$, $ax=x^4a$. Solve the equation $x^7=e$.

I started by observing that for $x=a$ we have that $a^2=a^5$, so $a^3=e$. Then I tried to left multiply the relation in the hypothesis by $x^3$, but it didn't help and now I am stuck.

EDIT: This is what the answer key says "take $a=x^7$ to get that $x^8=x^{11} \implies x^3=e$. Hence, $a=x^7=(x^3)^2 x=x \implies x=a$, which satisfies $x^7=e$".
To me, this seems blatantly wrong. Firstly, I don't think we can set $a$ to be equal to anything because we are only told that it exists, nothing more. Secondly, $a^7=a$ since $a^3=e$.
Could it be possible that this problem is wrong and the equation in fact has no solution?

Comment: I'm guessing $x^11$ should be $x^{11}$?

Comment: and I'm guessing $=>$ should be $\implies$?

Comment: We cannot take $a=x^7$, since there **exists** an $a$ such that $x^4=axa^{-1}$ for all $x\in G$. The question and the answer do not match.

Comment: Could it be, that the equation is $x^7=a$ instead of $x^7=e$? In that case, both your solution and the answer key makes sense.

Comment: Anyway, it is easy to check $[a,[a,y]]^7=e$ for all $y\in G$.  The question is are there more than conjugating these?

Comment: @DietrichBurde exactly my thoughts, I suspect that there is an error in the statement in the book.

Comment: @Winther could you give me more details, please? If I raise that relation to the $k^{\text{th}}$ power I will just get that $x^{4k}=ax^ka^{-1}$, which doesn't seem to help.

Comment: We have $x^{16} = ax^4a^{-1}$ but $x^4 = axa^{-1}$ so this gives $x^{16} = a^2 x a^{-2}$. Continue this way until you get $a^3\cdots a^{-3}$ and you know that $a^3=e$...

Comment: @Winther You only know $x^{63}=e$, not $x^3=e$.

Comment: I agree with @above and in our case we already have $x^7=e$ so this doesn't give any further information.

Comment: @Winther From $x^{16}=a^2xa^{-2}$ we get $x^{64}=a^2x^4a^{-2}=x$, and hence $x^{63}=e$. How do you get $x^{60}=e$?

Comment: @Winther I don't see where 60 come from.  $x^{4^3}=a^3xa^{-3}=x$ so $x^{63}=e$ is all you can conclude.  Then $[a,y]=y^3$ so $[a,[a,y]]^7=y^{63}=e$ is what I used above.

Comment: @user10354138 Yes, was a mental miscalculation, $x^{63} = e$ is correct (instead of $x^{64} = x^4$ which was what I had). Then the other step I suggested does not work directly.

Comment: It's interesting that Strichcoder has given what is obviously the answer hours ago, yet so much effort has still been given to solving the typo.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I think the problem with the typo is still interesting per se, IMHO.

Comment: @awllower - that's fine. It can be interesting to solve other problems. But because Strichcoder's comment had passed with only a few upvotes, I wanted to emphasize what seemed clear to me was the answer to the actual issue in the OP.

Answer (score 5):

As shown in the comments, $x^{63}=e,\,\forall x\in G$. Hence, for every $x$ in $G$, $(x^9)^7=e$. Conversely, if $x^7=e$, then $x=(x^4)^9$. So the solutions to the equation $x^7=e$ form the set $\left\{x^9\mid x\in G\right\}$.

> For the sake of completeness, let's show $x^{63}=e,\,\forall x\in G$ here. Since for every $x$ in $G$, $ax^4a^{-1}=x^{16}$, we see $x^{16}=a^2xa^{-2}$, and hence $x^{64}=a^3xa^{-3}=x$, thus $x^{63}=e$.

---

Hope this helps.