# Let $(H,\cdot)$ be a group, $e$ the identity, and $(H,\cdot)$ be s.t. $\exists a\in H$ s.t. $ax=x^4a,\forall x\in H$. Solve $x^7=e$.

Tags: group-theory

Let $(H,\cdot)$ve a group and $e$ the identity element.

The group $(H,\cdot)$ has the property that there is an $a\in H$ such that $$\:\forall x\in H,\:ax=x^4a$$

Solve the equation:
$$x^7=e$$
I proved that:

**Lemma**:

> $$\text{Let be}\: x,\:y\in H. \text{Then}\: x^2=y^2 \implies x=y$$

*Solution:*
$$x^2=y^2 \implies x^4=y^4\implies x^4a=y^4a\stackrel{ax=x^4a}{\implies} ax=ay\implies x=y$$

May somebody help me continue?

Comment: I would say, consider instead $x^8=x$. $x^8=x^4x^4=axa^{-1}axa^{-1}$...

Comment: Do you mean there exists $a\in H$ such that $\forall x\in H$, $ax=x^4a$? (as in, your quantifier is incorrectly placed, right?) Also, you say "solve" - what are you expecting the solution to be? You only really know two elements of $H$, right, $a$ and $e$ (and also powers of $e$), so you should be guessing that any solution is a power of $a$.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to know the source of this problem. The issue is that the answer seems to depend on the group $H$. In particular, no non-trivial power of $a$ is ever an answer (easy exercise: prove that $a$ has order $3$), while there are groups which have non-trivial solution (e.g $C_7\rtimes C_3$).

Comment: @user1729 in 7 semi 3, you can only find a that work with 1, 3, 9, or 15 possible x. The choice that seemed "obvious" to me only worked with 9.

Comment: see this problem:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3275017/solve-x7-e-in-a-group

Comment: @JackSchmidt Did my original comment say that every $x\not\in\langle a\rangle$ was a solution? I had thought that originally, but it is incorrect. If it made it to my comment, it has since been edited out.

Comment: @user1729 I mean that 7 semi 3 is not a possible value for the group H in this question. Such a group does not satisfy the hypothesis of this question.

Comment: @JackSchmidt Ah, yes, my calculation was not quite right! Anyhow, if $x$ is a non-trivial solution and $a$ is non-trivial then $\langle x, a\rangle$ is isomorphic to $C_7\rtimes C_3$, right? (Different orders give trivial intersection, while $ax=x^4a$ gives normality of $\langle x\rangle$, etc.) So there can be no groups satisfying the conditions of the question, right?